# Media query is not working for 768px ipad portrait

Tags: html, css, media-queries

My media query is not working for 768px ipad portrait.

If I change for **min-width** works perfect but affects the size when is on **desktop version** or some another resolution **more than 769px**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar-container.pressed .content-container {
    width: 93% !important;
  }
}
```

Someone can explain me that, and help how to solve? I just want make it work on 768px.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For iPads in portrait mode it is generally best to be more specific in the media queries, so try something like this:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { 
    /* Styles Here */
}
```

This way you target devices with screen width between `768px` and `1024px` which is what the iPad is, then you filter your targets by specifying the orientation as portrait.

You could try something like this - reducing the `max-width` - to minimize any other screens that it could effect, but I haven't tried it so can't verify it works.

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 770px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { 
    /* Styles Here */
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**iPhone 6 Media Queries**

```
/* iPhone 6 in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}

/* iPhone 6 in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}

/* iPhone 6 in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```

**iPhone 6 Plus Media Queries**

```
/* iPhone 6 Plus in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}

/* iPhone 6 Plus in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}

/* iPhone 6 Plus in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```

**iPhone 5 & 5S Media Queries**

```
/* iPhone 5 & 5S in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}

/* iPhone 5 & 5S in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}

/* iPhone 5 & 5S in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```

**iPhone 2G, 3G, 4, 4S Media Queries**
It's noteworthy that these media queries are also the same for iPod Touch generations 1-4.

```
/* iPhone 2G-4S in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}

/* iPhone 2G-4S in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}

/* iPhone 2G-4S in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```

**iPad**

```
/* iPad in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)  { /* STYLES GO HERE */}

/* iPad in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}

/* iPad in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```

**iPad 3 & 4 Media Queries**

```
/* If you're looking to target only 3rd and 4th generation Retina iPads (or tablets with similar resolution) to add @2x graphics, or other features for the tablet's Retina display, use the following media queries. */

/* Retina iPad in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}

/* Retina iPad in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}

/* Retina iPad in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```

**iPad 1 & 2 Media Queries**

```
/* If you're looking to supply different graphics or choose different typography for the lower resolution iPad display, the media queries below will work like a charm in your responsive design! */

/* iPad 1 & 2 in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1){ /* STYLES GO HERE */}

/* iPad 1 & 2 in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)  { /* STYLES GO HERE */}

/* iPad 1 & 2 in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```

**iPad mini**

```
/* iPad mini in portrait & landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)  { /* STYLES GO HERE */}

/* iPad mini in landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)  { /* STYLES GO HERE */}

/* iPad mini in portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)  { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```

Source:
http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/#iPad